# Android VideoView does not work

Tags: android

I play with a very simple example from the book "Android Studio Development" 6 Edition, for using VideoView class, codes as below:

```
final VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
videoView.setVideoPath("http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/android_book/movie.mp4");
videoView.start();
```

Note:(1) I setup:
                 in manifest.
    (2) I try the movie.mp4 link from my PC, it can be download to my PC to open

But I load this simple project to my physical device: Android 4.3, API 18. The device screen shows: "cannot play this video"

on the error log:
D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
E/MediaPlayer: Unable to to create media player
W/VideoView: Unable to open content: http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/android_book/movie.mp4

There are same fix ways on stackoverflow, but I just unable to use these to resolve my problem.

Anyone has tried this book's sample and found same problem and resolve it, please give me the help.

Thanks,

Sunny

Comment: Do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`?

Comment: May be a codec matter (audio or video algorith, audio or video data rate, GOP etc). Your device, outside your app, can play the same video?

Comment: Yes, I setup users-permission for INTERNET. Also my device can play video.